# How to add caller details to error stack trace in node.js?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise

I have a function called inner that performs a series of asinc operations:

```
function inner(input) {
    return step1(input)
    .then(step2)
    .then(step3)
    .catch((e) => {
        throw e
    })
}
```

I rethrow the error from inner so I could handle the error in caller level.

Here is a simple example:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    inner(req)
    .then(result => {
        res.render('foo', result)
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.render('error', e);

        //eventually this would be changed to logger.error(e)
        console.log(e);
    })
})
```

The problem is that when I log the error the stack trace shows only the function inner but not the caller file. If I would to use this function twice in my code and error happens then I would need to know which part of my code called it.

How can I add caller information to error stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

## Non-standard feature

Since [`Error.prototype.stack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack) document tags it as a non-standard feature, different platforms may have different behaviours and formats.

For example, I tested it in Chrome with following files:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="inner.js"></script>
    <script src="caller1.js"></script>
    <script src="caller2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

**inner.js**

```
function inner() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject(new Error('Oh no'))
  }).catch(e => { throw e })
}
```

**caller1.js** and **caller2.js**

```
inner().catch(e => { console.log(e.stack) })
```

And the result in **console**:

```
Error: Oh no
    at Promise (setup.js:3)
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at inner (setup.js:2)
    at caller1.js:1
Error: Oh no
    at Promise (setup.js:3)
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at inner (setup.js:2)
    at caller2.js:1
```

Both `inner()` and caller are showed in the stack trace.

## Workaround

In your case, you may manually log it in the caller's `catch()`.

If the code is executed in the browser, use [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) and its `src` property to get the filename.

## Edit: in Node.js

I tested it in Node.js v8.1.2, and the `inner()` and caller were both displayed as well.

By the way, a paragraph in the [document](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_stack) got my attection:

> It is important to note that frames are only generated for JavaScript
>   functions. If, for example, execution synchronously passes through a
>   C++ addon function called `cheetahify`, which itself calls a JavaScript
>   function, the frame representing the `cheetahify` call will not be
>   present in the stack traces

This may be the reason we get inconsistent results.

In any case, I'm afraid you still have to manually log the filename, which depends on how you import and execute them in the first place.

Comment: After you comment " different platforms may have different behaviours and formats." I realized that I had forgot to mention that I am interested in node.js

Comment: Node.js part added.